# php: routine javascript browser does not appear until the end

Tags: javascript, php, google-chrome, progress-bar

We felt in a procedure in php to show a process bar while performing a task, but in the Chrome browser does not display the bar until the process ends. In other browsers like Chromium it works perfectly and shows the progress bar. Any suggestions?

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN">
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Progress Bar</title>
</head>
<body>
<!-- Progress bar holder -->
<div id="progress" style="width:500px;border:1px solid #ccc;"></div>
<!-- Progress information -->
<div id="information" style="width"></div>
<?php
// Total processes
$total = 10;
// Loop through process
for($i=1; $i<=$total; $i++){
    // Calculate the percentation
    $percent = intval($i/$total * 100)."%";

    // Javascript for updating the progress bar and information
    echo '<script language="javascript">
    document.getElementById("progress").innerHTML="<div style=\"width:'.$percent.';background-color:#ddd;\">&nbsp;</div>";
    document.getElementById("information").innerHTML="'.$i.' row(s) processed.";
    </script>';


// This is for the buffer achieve the minimum size in order to flush data
    echo str_repeat(' ',1024*64);


// Send output to browser immediately
    flush();


// Sleep one second so we can see the delay
    sleep(1);
}
// Tell user that the process is completed
echo '<script language="javascript">document.getElementById("information").innerHTML="Process completed"</script>';
?>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm gonna be one of those annoying people that ask why are you doing something.

Do you actually need to stream the data from the server to the browser ?

Unless you are sending huge amounts of generated data to the user, there is really no need for such measures.

Because you are not using WebSockets, you could save the information about the process into the cookie, so that you do not have to store it anywhere else, and it is related to an individual client, and send an AJAX request to a dedicated page that will return the percentage, or the state of this process.

While the process is going on you just need to call setcookie with the correct values, something like

```
setcookie($name, $value, $expiration /*<--- does not matter*/);
```

and in the dedicated page that returns this value

```
return $_COOKIE[$name];      //<--- $name the same as in setcookie, 
                             //this should probably return JSON
```

and in the js code you would ( with jquery, cause its easier )

```
$.get(page, function(data) 
    { 
        document.getElementById("progress").innerHTML = 
              '<div style="width: data;background-color:#ddd;"></div>';
    }
```

Hope this helps.